# rank condition vs determinant as a polynomial

Tags: determinant, matrix-rank

Could anyone help me to show how these two statements are equivalent?

$(1)$ rank $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda I-Y\\X\end{bmatrix}=n\forall \lambda\in \mathbb{C}$

$(2)$ For any monic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda^n+a_1\lambda^{n-1}+\dots+a_n,a_i\in\mathbb{R},\exists$ a  matrix with constant entries $M$ such that $\det(\lambda I-Y+MX)=p(\lambda)$

given, $M$ is $n\times p$, $Y$ is $n\times n$, and $X$ is $p\times n$